# Checking total sum in Javascript is greater than a number

Tags: javascript, if-statement

My script calculates the total value of selected products on a page and returns a total in a span. I have altered the script so that a second span appears with a button when the total value of the products is greater than 2000, however when the value drops below 2000, the button still shows.

```
function calctotal(){
var total = 0;

    $(".calc").each(function(){
    var a=this.value * $(this).attr('data-price');
    total+=parseFloat(a);


});
$( "span.total" ).html('Your furniture total is &pound;' + total.toFixed(2) );

if (total.toFixed(2) > 2000) {

$( "span.basketbutton" ).html('<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Furniture selections to Basket" style="margin-left:40px">');   

} 

}
```

Comment: Try searching google for your exact title: https://www.google.com/search?q=Checking+total+sum+in+Javascript+is+greater+than+a+number

Comment: You don't clear the span if you call `calctotal` a second time, so when the value drops below 2000 it will still retain the old value. Use `$( "span.basketbutton" ).empty()` before the if statement.

Comment: Instead of adding and removing HTML, you should just hide and show it.  Or if it's a submit button, enable and disable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you never removed it and toFixed returns string which may cause unexpected output so removed it

Try:

```
if (total > 2000) {    
    $( "span.basketbutton" ).html('<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Furniture selections to Basket" style="margin-left:40px">');      
 } 
else{
  $( "span.basketbutton" ).html('');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the `else` part of your `if` statement, where you should be removing the button when the total drops below 2000.

By the way, `toFixed(2)` is unnecessary as it would convert the truncated value of `total` to a string.  You would want to perform a numerical comparison: `total > 2000`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the `toFixed(2)` in this case, but be careful with that. You never cleared the `span.basketbutton` after the first time that total > 2000. So, you need to clear the HTML inside `span.backetbutton` if is not cleared, for that you can use `html()` or `empty()` function.

```
calcTotal = function(){
    var total,a = 0;

    $('.calc').each(function(i, el) {
        a = el.val() * el.data('price');
        total+=parseFloat(a);
    });

    $( "span.total" ).html('Your furniture total is &pound;' + total.toFixed(2) );

    if (total > 2000) {
        $( "span.basketbutton" ).html('<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Furniture selections to Basket" style="margin-left:40px">');   
    }
    else if("span.basketbutton").children().length>0){
        $(this).empty();
    }
};
```

#### Extras:

- If you're writing jQuery, then avoid to use pure Javascript ;)
- Use `data()` to access HTML5 data elements with jQuery.
- Instead of using `html()` function, you could do something like toggle() on this case to maintain your code cleaner and separate `HTML` from `JS` code.